# Xamarin Android crash only on Android 10

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-10.0

I have a project that works perfectly on android 11, 9, 8, 7.1.
The bug only occurs in version 10

Everything is fine during the tests. The error only occurs in the production version.
This is a error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:  
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3271)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3410)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks 
(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2017)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7397)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

Have any of you had a similar bug and did you fix it?

Comment: Where is the code that triggers the exception?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know which code is generating excemption.

Comment: Do you have any crash reporting/logging enabled in your app?  Have you asked the users about the circumstances causing the crash?

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have access to ANR errors in the Google Play console. How enable raporting in app?

Comment: use a tool like appcenter.ms or raygun.io

Comment: Thanks Jason, I'll try the Center app and should deal with the bug. Subject to be closed.